# How to retain mocked data in service

Tags: nullpointerexception, mockito, junit5

I have a service called AcctBeneficiaryService and trying to write junit test case for it and getting failed due to Null pointer exception at for loop

My service would look like this
     @Service
     public class AcctBeneficiaryService {

```
 public List<AcctBeneficiary> getAccountBeneficiaryDetails(long rltshpId) throws Exception {

 RltshpData rlshpData = rltshpClient.getRltshpInfo(rltshpId);

List<AcctBeneficiary> acctBeneficiaries = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Long> conidList = new ArrayList<>();

    **for(BigDecimal account : rlshpData.getAccounts())**
 (Null pointer here)   {

        AcctBeneficiary acctBeneficiary = new AcctBeneficiary();
        Account accountInfo = new Account();
```

My Test Case would look like this

```
 public void testGetAccountBeneficiaryDetails() throws Exception {

   //Initializing required objects for Mock
    RltshpData rlshpData = new RltshpData();
    RltshpInfo rltshpInfo = new RltshpInfo();
    List<BigDecimal> accounts = new ArrayList<>();

    //Mock Data for rltshpInfo
    rltshpInfo.setIrNo(135434);
    rltshpInfo.setIsoCtryCd("US");
    rltshpInfo.setRltshpNa("Individual");

    //Mock Data for accounts
    accounts.add(new BigDecimal(4534));
    //accounts.add(new BigDecimal(4564));

    //populate mocking data to the object
    rlshpData.setRltshpInfo(rltshpInfo);
    rlshpData.setAccounts(accounts);
  when(service.getAccountBeneficiaryDetails(new Long(1234))).thenReturn(Mockito. 
  <AcctBeneficiary>anyList());
    assertNotNull(acctBeneficiaryList);
```

Error Details
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at 
      .fplbeneficiariesrest.service.AcctBeneficiaryService.getAccountBeneficiaryDetails
    (AcctBeneficiaryService.java:64)
    at

```
  .fplbeneficiariesrest.service.AcctBeneficiaryServiceTest.
 testGetAccountBeneficiaryDetails(AcctBeneficiaryServiceTest.java:160)
```

Null pointer is at 
**for(BigDecimal account : rlshpData.getAccounts())** This for loop is not able to take the Mocked data as rlshpData.getAccounts() is getting executed before

Comment: Share please all code for test class.  
 If your goal is testing method `getAccountBeneficiaryDetails` why did you mock it by this `when().thenReturn()`?